# Which of these phrase is correct

Tags: expressions

I was reading a text in an English book and it was stated that between "**taller from is the correct use from taller than**

I want to know how true this is

Comment: Some examples need to be added to at least try to justify each phrase.

Comment: What you have quoted is complete nonsense. Either you have misunderstood, or the book is not to be trusted.

Comment: @Colin Fine, I think it's not so. Andrade, stronger from his layoff, targets top 154 pounders - Ring TV.

Comment: @Khan: "stronger" is somethiing you can make yourself be. "Taller" is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct grammatically, depending on the context.

If you compare two things or persons with each other, you must use "than" after taller, for example, he is taller than me.

You can use "from" after taller if you use  "from" to mean as a result of or by means of, such as you can grow one inch taller from swimming/from this exercise.

Comment: But your second example is so hugely unlikely to occur, that "taller from" can be discounted. In ordinary English only "taller than" makes sense.

Comment: Andrade, stronger from his layoff, targets top 154 pounders - Ring TV.